# What data structure should I use if these data would need prices for each?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have this product data where I would also need to subtract the quantity of the colors once an order was placed for the specific product.

For now, this is my data structure where the `colorMap` is a Map.

[image]

Problem: What if I need to have different prices for each of the colors? Should I change the `colorMap` into an array?

Comment: What does 20 represent for Black?

Comment: @AlexMamo the quantity of the color black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the `price` of the color is missing. Assuming that you have a different price for each color, the most appropriate way to solve this would be to create inside the document, an array of Color objects called `colors` like this:

```
$docId
  |
  --- cat: "ML"
  |
  --- colors (array)
  |    |
  |    --- 0
  |    |   |
  |    |   --- colorName: "Black"
  |    |   |
  |    |   --- quantity: 20
  |    |   |
  |    |   --- price: 11.99
  |    |
  |    --- 1
  |        |
  |        --- colorName: "Green"
  |        |
  |        --- quantity: 5
  |        |
  |        --- price: 14.99
  |
  --- price: 200 //Remove that if not necessary
  |
  --- prodName: "Thumbler"
  |
  --- size: "500"
```

In this way, you can simply read the array and calculate the total.

Since you didn't set a tag, we don't know if you are building an app that is for Android, iOS, or web. If by chance it's for Android, here is a useful article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: I actually forgot to add that I'm building this in Reactjs. In that way, would I be able to subtract the number of colors automatically as well once the order was placed for a certain product? Also, there will be instances where multiple products are placed.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the programming language is, you can keep the above structure. And yes, you can read the array and calculate the total like this: `(20 * 11.99) + (5 * 14.99) + ...`. If there will be instances where multiple products are placed, then you should do the same thing for each product.

Comment: would it be possible to automatically subtract the `quantity: 20` if the chosen color was placed? Like once placing an order for the product Tumbler with the color `Black` it will be automatically subtracted where it would update to like this `quantity: 19`?

Comment: Yes, but you have to write code for that. Give it a try and if you have a hard time implementing it, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.